# calloc not allocating correct data when returned to pointer reference from a dereferenced double pointer in a function

Tags: c, gcc, calloc, double-pointer

I am trying to use calloc to dynamically allocate data to a struct pointer within another struct.

If i allocate directly from the main routine, there is no issue.
If i pass a double pointer to an initialization function with ** as parameter, and use the arrow operator to reference the address, the data is not properly allocated and i get a "floating point error" while encoding the hash.

This code runs the way i want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/*create item structure, this will hold allocated pointers to the key/value elements.*/
struct H_item_t{
    char* key;
    int* value;
};
typedef struct H_item_t H_item_t;

/*create the table structure, this will point to the initial item address.*/
struct HashTable_T {
    size_t size;
    H_item_t* items;
};
typedef struct HashTable_T HashTable_T;

int encodeKey(HashTable_T* table, char* key){
    /*encode the string*/
    size_t index = 0;   //initialize value to full
    size_t length = strlen(key);    //get length of string
    size_t i = 0; //initialize loop;.

    for (; i < length; i++) {
    index ^= (key[i]);
    };
    index %= table->size;
    return index;
}

void hashItem(HashTable_T* table, char* string, int value ){
    H_item_t* ptr1;
    int index = encodeKey(table,string);
    ptr1= &table->items[index];
    ptr1->key=string;
    ptr1->value=(int)value;
}

int* getValue(HashTable_T* table, char* key){
    int index = encodeKey(table,key);
    H_item_t* ptr1;
    ptr1= &table->items[index]; 
    return ptr1->value;
}

void deleteTable(HashTable_T* table){
    free(table->items);
    free(table);
};

void initTable(HashTable_T** table, int size){

    (*table) = (HashTable_T*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable_T));
    (*table)->items = (H_item_t*)calloc(size,sizeof(H_item_t));   
};

int main()
{

HashTable_T* ht1 = malloc(sizeof(HashTable_T));
ht1->size=10;
ht1->items=(H_item_t*)calloc(ht1->size,sizeof(H_item_t));
   
hashItem(ht1,"A",3);
hashItem(ht1,"B",2);
hashItem(ht1,"C",1);
hashItem(ht1,"D",100);

printf("value returned from get: %x\n",(int)getValue(ht1,"D"));

deleteTable(ht1);  
}
```

If I use the initTable() fxn;

```
HashTable_T* ht1;
initTable(&ht1,10);
```

instead of;

```
HashTable_T* ht1 = malloc(sizeof(HashTable_T));
ht1->size=10;
ht1->items=(H_item_t*)calloc(ht1->size,sizeof(H_item_t));
```

I get "floating point exception" during runtime

Comment: `initTable` does not set the `size` field.

Comment: Make sure the type casting is done correctly. ptr1->value=(int*)value;

Comment: the second parameter should set this value to 10 which is then passed to calloc as int. I have also tried as; initTable(&ht1,(int)10);

Comment: "*the second parameter should set this value to 10*". Yes it should. But the point is the code as shown doesn't do that. Missing `(*table)->size = size;`

Comment: @kaylum thanks! that was the issue. I will answer it with solution

Comment: You have declared the `value` field of `H_item_t` as an `int *`.  But it would make more sense, and in fact you are using it, as a plain `int`.  Suggest declaring it that way, too.

Comment: You probably know this, but: So far, you have no provision for handing collisions in your hash table.

Comment: The line `ptr1->key=string` in function `hashitem` presumes that you can use the caller-passed string on a long-term basis, i.e. it creates an alias which will fail (become dangling) if the caller passes a pointer to a string which is later deallocated.  Usual practice would be to use [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) here, although that does then slightly complicate the job of your `deleteTable` function.

Comment: @SteveSummit Working on the collision at this moment. looking into strdup as well. Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION;

Dont forget to initialize all members within the structure.

This is working code for the initTable fxn;

```
void initTable(HashTable_T** table, int size){
    //return allocated memory to the pointer that is held in the double pointer
    (*table) = (HashTable_T*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable_T));
    (*table)->size = size;
    (*table)->items = (H_item_t*)calloc((*table)->size,sizeof(H_item_t));

};
```

I forgot to initialize ..size within the structure from within the function. error resulted